# PostgreSQL Query export to CSV with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tableau-api

```
$sf = "\\\\domain\\dept\\dcgsi\\Extracts\\Tableau_Unlicensed_Users.csv"

if (Test-Path $sf){
    Remove-Item $sf
}

$query = @"
\\copy (SELECT Name 
FROM _users 
WHERE licensing_role_name = 'Unlicensed')
TO $sf
WITH CSV DELIMITER ','
"@ 
$conn = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection

# use existing 64 bit ODBC System DSN that we set up manually
$conn.Open('PostgreSQL30')  
$conn.Execute($query)
$conn.Close()
```

I keep getting an error about "\" on the line with the `$conn.Execute()` when I try and do this.  I assume it has to do with character escaping and maybe I am doing it wrong.

Is there a better way to do this with PowerShell if I just need to get the name field of any record from _users and output it to CSV?

Eventually I will be adding more to this to loop through each record in the CSV and execute a tabcmd to remove all the users that are unlicensed.

Comment: Please post the error message. See the site help on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Meh; I finally found another post that actually made some sense.  Posting my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sf = "\\domain\dept\dcgsi\Extracts\Tableau_Unlicensed_Users.csv"

if (Test-Path $sf){
    Remove-Item $sf
}

$query = @"
SELECT Name 
FROM _users 
WHERE licensing_role_name = 'Unlicensed'
"@ 

function Get-ODBC-Data{
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=PostgreSQL30;"
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query, $conn)
    $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    (New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter($cmd)).Fill($ds) | Out-Null
    $conn.Close()
    $ds.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $sf
}

Get-ODBC-Data
```

This did like 99% of what I need; I just have to process the csv now and drop the first two lines.  The first line is a type info message and the second is the column header.

Comment: Use `Export-Csv -NoType` to get rid of the type information line.

Comment: If you don't want the column titles in the output use `ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content` instead of `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I'll go and modify that.